# {{#link-to}} helper not working with supplied model

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following index template:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {{#each agent in model}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{#link-to "agents.show" agent}}{{agent.name}}{{/link-to}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have defined a `link-to` to a show route, but this is not working: it is creating the following link:

```
http://localhost:9001/#/nodes/agents/undefined/show
```

With an `undefined` dynamic segment. If instead I directly supply the `.id` of the agent:

```
<td>{{#link-to "agents.show" agent.id}}{{agent.name}}{{/link-to}}</td>
```

The link is created fine. But I do not want to do this because that means a round-trip to the server, while I already have the model available in the index controller. Besides, the `link-to` helper has always worked fine with a supplied model (I have refactored my app quite a bit, and I am unable to find the source of this problem)

Why is `link-to` able to use the object id for the dynamic segment, but it is not able to pass the full object to the linked route? What can I do to further debug this issue?

Comment: Are you using ember data? Is your model name agent? Is your dynamic segment `agent_id` ?

Comment: Yes, ember-data, model `Agent`, dynamic segment `agent_id`

Comment: Could you add your router and model to the question.

Comment: Why do you say that you would be "round-tripping" to get the id? I would think you have the id available on the client already...

Comment: @BasementKeyboardHero: Thanks for your help, but I found the problem: I have implemented a buggy `serialize` method in the route.

Comment: @KalmanHazins: as stated in the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/#toc_the-code-link-to-code-helper): `If there is no model to pass to the helper, you can provide an explicit identifier value instead. The value will be filled into the dynamic segment of the route, and will make sure that the model hook is triggered.`. Whenever the model is triggered, a backend access will be performed (depends on your implementation of the model hook, but that is the normal case for dynamic data)